# How to add append an element on .clone() that is a button that will remove the clone

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <table id="component_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Component</th>
                <th>Component Type</th>
                <th>Component Thickness</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="component_tb">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $roofComponentDropDown ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $roofComponentTypeDropDown ?></td> 
                <td><input id="component_thickness" name="component_thickness[]" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" />
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Which looks like this in the browser, just to give you a better idea of what I am trying to do.

When the user clicks on the `+` button I run this JQuery function here:

```
$(function() {
    var $componentTB = $("#component_tb"),
        $firstTRCopy = $componentTB.children('tr').first().clone();
    $("#addRows").click(function() {
        $componentTB.append($firstTRCopy.clone());
    });
});
```

Which will clone my `<tr>` and append it onto my table making it look something like this: [image]

Now here is my problem, while I am appeneding in the new row I am also trying to insert another `<td>` into my table with a link or button named `remove` that when clicked will remove that added `<tr>`.

Here is what im trying:

```
$componentTB.append($firstTRCopy.clone()).after("<td><a href='#'>Remove</a></td>");
```

which doesn't exactly give me the output I need[image]

that's close, and I think I could get it to work if I change some CSS..(I am trying to get the link where the red line is)

Here is my attempt with a `-` button (preferred)

```
$componentTB.append($firstTRCopy.clone()).after("<input type='button' value='-' id='addRows' />");
```

However the output is not working at all how I need it to and is just adding the buttons side by side as opposed to being apart of the table row that is cloned.

[image]

How can I get the `-` buttons to be added into my cloned row and, how would I get it to remove the row that the remove link/button was clicked on?

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you need a fourth  in your table for that extra button to live in. This needs to exist on the first row as well as all other rows (it just doesn't need to have the '-' button in the  tag).

As far as getting the row to be deleted, you can add an id column to your row to use for deletion.

This is a working Html page that does what you want:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Component</th>
            <th>Component Type</th>
            <th>Component Thickness</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="component_tb">
        <tr id="row0">
            <td><select><option value="test1">Test1</option><option value="test2">Test2</option></select><td>
            <td><select><option value="test1">Test1</option><option value="test2">Test2</option></select><td>
            <td><select><input type="text" /></select><td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var $componentTB = $("#component_tb"),
        $firstTRCopy = $("#row0").clone();
        $idVal = 1;
    $("#addRows").click(function() {
        var copy = $firstTRCopy.clone();
        var newId = 'row' +$idVal;
        copy.attr('id', newId);
        $idVal += 1;
        copy.children('td').last().append("<a href=\"javascript:remove('" + newId + "')\">Remove</a>");
        $componentTB.append(copy);
    });
});
function remove(id){
    $("#" + id).remove();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I would also encourage you to take a look at two-way binding such as Angular or Knockout.js. These allow you to connect a javascript model to your data and will handle removal and adding new rows much more cleanly.

**EDIT:** If you want to change what is being attached to the final td tag just alter the append in:

```
copy.children('td').last().append("<a href=\"javascript:remove('" + newId + "')\">Remove</a>");
```

Comment: is there a way to append a button instead of a link and get the same effect?

Comment: Yes I edited the answer to include what you need to alter. For a button just change it to be "<button onclick="javascript:remove('" + newId + "')\">Remove</button>" I believe (I can't test it right now).

Comment: I will test it when I get the chance, and comment back here with the results (probably tomorrow), thanks for the answer.